# X students composing a team

Tags: phrase-request

I am working on my resume and I am looking for a short way to introduce that I was working on a project with X other students.

I am currently using "Team of X students." at the beginning of the paragraph, but it does not sound right. I then thought about "X students per team" and other variations, but now I am confused.

How would you say that in proper English?

Here is a more detailed sample:

> Programming of a game
>   Team of X students. Development of a game using C++ and SFML.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 'a team of X students', but I guess we can't reliably give you the best alternative as that's subjective, and can't give you a definite piece of advice since we haven't seen the sentence.

Comment: Your entire paragraph seems really odd, particularly for a resume. It seems extremely informal. Things like "Aperture science, we do what we must because we can" sounds like a tag line for a product... Saying that you did an amazing job and patting yourself on the back doesn't tell a potential employer *anything* about the project. Lots of people love projects that they made... that doesn't make them good projects.

Comment: It's a quote from a song in a game (Portal - Still Alive), it's not in my resume. I wrote what I had in my mind because it does not matter, I am only looking for the sentence that explains that the project was made by a team of X students.

Comment: DRz - In my experience, when people try to cloak what they are asking about with contrived examples, it often creates distractions that muddy the waters and make the question more difficult to answer.

Comment: I did not mention it well enough but I am looking for a quite generic sentence. I used contrived examples so I am sure answers would not "overfit" the given paragraph.

Comment: What J.R said **is** generic. It's pretty standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the phrase ***as part of*** would work well here. You could say:

> Developed a game using C++ and SFML **as part of** a team of four students

Or you could start off with that:

> **As part of** a team with four students, developed a game using C++ and SFML.

Either way, the phrase indicates the software was developed by a team, and you were a part of that team.

If you led the team, instead of being a mere rank-and-file member of it, you could adjust accordingly, perhaps by using *while*:

> Developed a game using C++ and SFML **while leading** a team of four students

Comment: Are you supposed to detail a project using the past tense?

Comment: @DRz Well, you did it... in the past. If you're *currently* working on it, it wouldn't be complete.

Comment: @DRz - This isn't a resume-writing workshop, but [take a look at this example](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f9/51/ae/f951ae5c043546f0eb72e6eb529eb780.jpg). What was done in the past is written using past tense.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more question, `As part of a team with four students` ... does that mean we were 5 in total or would I be included in the 4?

Comment: @DRz You're included. Four is the total.